# Internal Redirection with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to achieve the following:

User access: s1.domain.com
Browser stays: s1.domain.com
Server goes to: s2.domain.com/folder/

s1.domain.com & s2.domain.com are pointing to the same DocumentRoot

The following is not working - it is actually making a browser redirect (took from another question from stackoverflow)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =s1.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://s2.domain.com/folder/ [QSA,P,L]
```

Any ideas what can I do?

Comment: If you change the domain, it will do that.  If they point to the same doc root, then just take the domain off ;)

Comment: if you want the browser URL to say `s1.domain.com` but show content from `s2.domain.com/folder/` you need to use some ReverseProxy approach.

Comment: You need to add the proxying rules as well. `P` flag by itself is NOT enough: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html

Comment: Wouldn't `http://s2.domain.com/folder/` be same as `http://s1.domain.com/folder/` since they both point to same DocumentRoot?

Comment: yes they are. so should i just do: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ s1.domain.com/folder/ [QSA,P,L]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use proxy pass in apache vhost (virtual host configuration for your domain)

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPassMatch /(.*)    http://s2.domain.com/folder/$1
```